# JavaFx Concurrency Event

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-8, concurrency

I have a problem in JavaFx code.
I have one dialog box. Which has 2 buttons UPDATE NOW and UPDATE LATER.
My problem is : when I click on "UPDATE LATER" the dialog box should close and after 30 mins again it should pop up the same dialog box.
My main thread will be running only. I just need to remind it again after 30 mins whenever I click on UPDATE LATER.

Please help how can I do that in javaFx.

```
ButtonType[] buttonTypes = new ButtonType[2];
buttonTypes[0] =  new ButtonType("Update Now", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
buttonTypes[1] = new ButtonType("Update Later", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
EventHandler[] eventHandlers = new EventHandler[2];
eventHandlers[0] = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                   ;
                }
            };
                    
eventHandlers[1] = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
 }
 };     
Dialog.AlertDialog(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, Main.productName, "Update Confirmation", "New Update is available. DO you want to update ?", buttonTypes, Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL, StageStyle.DECORATED, stage, eventHandlers);
```

Comment: Use a `PauseTransition`.

Comment: @James_D can you pls explain more

Comment: @James_D Thanks it was really helpful. One more question I need to have same functionality when we click on (X) : close the dialog box . How can we do that ? Any leads?

Comment: It’s really better just to use the mechanism defined in `Dialog` to detect what choices the user made - see the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do something after some period of time, use a `PauseTransition`.

In this case, you can do

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.minutes(30));
    delay.setOnFinished(evt -> {
        // whatever you need to do in 30 minutes....
    });
    delay.play();
}
```

Comment: I have one more doubt,  for example I have PauseTransition for 1 hour and before completing it, I need to stop it. I dont want it to execute anything after 1 hour and completely stop the timer. Is it possible?

Comment: Don’t use the word “doubt” when you mean “question”. It comes off as slightly insulting. Doesn’t `delay.stop()` do what you need?